# Htaccess forward with query params

Tags: .htaccess, apache2, angular5, forwarding, query-string

I'm struggling with forwarding one service call with query params:
i want this:

```
https://myexample.center/myServlet?service=MyService&param1=a&param2=b&param3=etc
```

to be forwarded to:

```
http://myexample.center:8080/myServlet?service=MyService&param1=a&param2=b&param3=etc
```

Other calls to https://myexample.center/SDServlet?service=sthElse should not be affected

i'm grateful for any hint

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who is curious how i solved it:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} service=MyService
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://myexample.center:8080/%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,NC]
```

Working example for the same can be tested at [.htaccess tester](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=c76a496f-078a-5e9b-8b90-9203c70d9698)

Comment: Thanks for your efforts.